# The type 'xxx' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, reference, assemblies, tfsbuild

I have been scouring the internet for an answer on this and could really use the help.

I've already looked at other posts regarding this error and none of those answers helped me.

The full error is,

The type 'xxx' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'xxx, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The solution builds fine locally, but the error occurs when I trigger a build on the build server.

Here's what I've done so far in an attempt to resolve this:

- Ensured all project references are correct(Had an Architect review it
  with me)
- Changed the 'SpecificVersion' property to true
- Removed the    reference and added it back(In VS2012 and edited
  the .csproj file    itself)
- Built solution locally on the build server, it passes
- **EDIT** - I should also mention I have built this solution on two different build servers and still get the same error

I'm using VS2012 and TFS2012 to do this.

I would really appreciate any help, thanks.

**UPDATE:**I just did an MSBuild on the build server but changed the configuration to "Release" and was able to reproduce parts of the error.  Some key differences though is that the version it's looking for is suddenly 1.3.1.15 instead of 0.0.0.0 and the PublicKeyToken is no longer null.  Does anyone know what this could mean?  The assembly's version is supposed to be 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that the platforms are compatible? (i.e. making sure that a .NET 4.0 assembly isn't referencing a .NET 4.5 assembly, or a .NET 4 Client Profile assembly isn't referencing a .NET 4 full assembly)

Comment: Yeah, everything is being run under .NET 4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after putting in a few more hours with my Architect, we found the issue.  Our developers had multiple copies of the same dll buried in various folders in our Source Control.  One of the projects was referencing the incorrect .dll.

After fixing the references and removing the extra uneeded .dlls, the error is gone and our builds are finally working! :)

Comment: Use Nuget for that - will make your life much simpler.

Comment: @BenCollins How? What would you suggest?

Comment: Package the needed assembly into a nuget package and then reference it, rather than an assembly sitting on the disk.  It should be a pretty rare (not never, but rare) circumstance that a direct assembly is required.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you tried building solution on the test server. Did you use visual studio 2012 to build the solution or did you actually run msbuild?

The accurate test would be to use msbuild similar to this:

MSBuild MySolution.sln /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="CPU Any"

You can actually get the exact command by looking at the build logs for TFS Build, it will list the build command it executed and simply run it yourself (you'll need to remove extra stuff TFS Build adds for logging)

After that you can run the same command on your local machine and see if it passes.

Another thing to try is to set "copy local" for all assemblies in the project.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used MSBuild on the test server, and I just checked the "Copy Local" settings and they are already set to true for the project. :(

Comment: so it does build using msbuild on the build server? also do you use standard xaml for tfs build or is it a custom/modified one? Now about build configuration: what is your setting for "Clean Workspace" in build process parameters? When build fails, do you see all the source code in "Build Agent Folder" and is that the solution you compiling when running MSBuild?

Comment: Yeah, it builds using msbuild on the build server.  I'm using the standard xaml process template, and my "Clean Workspace" is set to "Outputs".  But I've set it to "All" as well and ran the build with no luck.  I've checked the build folder on the server and it does have all the source code when running msbuild.